# MicroPython - Micro:bit | Grove - Ultrasonic Ranger | Create driver for module

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I'm trying to translate the python code for Raspberry to MicroBit MicroPython for driving a Grove - Ultrasonic Ranger module with MicroPython.

http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Ultrasonic_Ranger/

https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/grove.py/blob/master/grove/grove_ultrasonic_ranger.py

I did this, the syntaxe is okay:

```
from microbit import *
import time


_TIMEOUT1 = 1000
_TIMEOUT2 = 10000


def _get_distance():
    pin0.write_digital(0)
    time.sleep_us(2)
    pin0.write_digital(1)
    time.sleep_us(10)
    pin0.write_digital(0)


    t0 = time.ticks_us()
    count = 0
    while count < _TIMEOUT1:
        if pin0.read_digital():
            display.set_pixel(1, 1, 5)
            break
        count += 1
    if count >= _TIMEOUT1:
        return None

    t1 = time.ticks_us()
    count = 0
    while count < _TIMEOUT2:
        if not pin0.read_digital():
            display.set_pixel(0, 0, 5)
            break
        count += 1
    if count >= _TIMEOUT2:
        return None

    t2 = time.ticks_us()



    dt = int(time.ticks_diff(t1,t0) * 1000000)
    # The problem is upside !


    if dt > 530:
        return  None

    distance = (time.ticks_diff(t2,t1) * 1000000 / 29 / 2)    # cm


    return distance


def get_distance():
    while True:
        dist = _get_distance()
        if dist:
            return dist

#Appel de la fonction get_distance(void) et affichage sur le display
display.scroll(get_distance())
```

But i have a big value for `dt` i don't know why...
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The Seeed Studio code does timing using Python's `time.time()` function. From [the help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time):

> `time.time()` → float
>
> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.

Your code uses MicroPython's `time.ticks_us()` function. From [its help](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html#utime.ticks_us):

> `utime.ticks_ms()`
>
> Returns an increasing millisecond counter with an arbitrary reference point, that wraps around after some value.
>
> ...
>
> `utime.ticks_us()`
>
> Just like ticks_ms() above, but in microseconds.

So the numbers you get in your version will be 10^6 times larger than the original Python code. It looks as if you're already multiplying the time differences by 10^6 to turn them into microseconds, so just remove this coefficient from your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

To run Ultrasonic Ranger module with MicroPython, you can just use [this library](https://github.com/MeqdadDev/microbit-micropython-samples/blob/main/External%20Components%20with%20microbit/Ultrasonic%20Sensor/ultrasonic.py). where I modularized a distance function into a module. So you can import it and call the distance function as in this example below:

```
from microbit import *
from ultrasonic import Ultrasonic

# default pins in Ultrasonic library are:
# trigger: pin13
# echo: pin15

ultrasonic_sensor = Ultrasonic()
# or
# ultrasonic_sensor = Ultrasonic(trig=pin13, echo=pin15)

while True:
    distance_value = ultrasonic_sensor.measure_distance_cm()
    display.scroll(str(int(distance_value)))
    sleep(2000)
```

I've tested it on micro:bit v2 with an [Ultrasonic module from Elecrow](https://www.elecrow.com/crowtail-ultrasonic-ranging-sensor.html) and their [Crowtail-Base Shield for Microbit](https://www.elecrow.com/crowtail-base-shield-for-microbit.html).